# Two y-axis pgfplot with ylabel and width=\linewidth badly aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, pgfplots, margins

I am trying to draw a `pgfplot` with to different y-axis with their respective label in a full line width and I can't get an alignment of the whole `tikzpicture` within the margins. The problem seems to come from the ylabel which, on the left axis shift the plot to the right, and on the right axis is plotted out of the picture, ie in the margin. I try to add the `ylabel style={overlay}` so I get the plot centered but both `ylabel` are this time in the margins. For sure, I can put a `0.95\linewidth` but I don't find this solution good enough since it isn't generalist.

Does anyone knows how can I fix this small example in an automatically way (meaning that `pgfplot` or `tikz` finds the right width alone)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\centering{}
\hrule{}
I\hfill I\hfill I\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis x line*=top,
  ylabel={$y=x^{2}$ label},
  ]
  \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  xmin=0,xmax=15,
  domain=0:15,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  ylabel={$y=x$ label},
  ]
  \addplot[red] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces this badly aligned plot

[image]

Comment: It seems your plot is too wide- have you tried changing `width=\linewidth` to something else?

Comment: I don't want to solve it this way. I would like the `tikzpicture` find the good width automatically so the solution will be the same for all my plots. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Care to define what is mean by "good width", or "right width"?  If you use something like `0.95\linewidth` it seems to work fine. If you want precise calculations you would need to adjust for the axis labels (which may be of different sizes).

Comment: I would like to add "the problem seems to come from the `ylabel` which, on the left axis shift the plot to the right, and on the right axis is plotted out of the picture, ie in the margin" in the description of the problem but due to the picture within the post, I can't edit it anymore since I earn some reputation.

Comment: @Sigmun: Would you be happy if the graph was just aligned properly, i.e. slightly protruding into both margins? Or do you want the graph to take up exactly the width of the surrounding text?

Comment: @Jake: I answer you by editing my post.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, if you draw something that is wider than the line width, the object will extend past the right margin. You have two possibilities:

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
  \end{tikzpicture}}
```

that will leave the axis' labels in the left and right margins; or

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
  \end{tikzpicture}}
```

(with the `graphicx` package) that will rescale the diagram to fit the line width.

Of course, the best solution is to say

```
width=.8\linewidth
```

(or what you prefer) and forget about boxing and rescaling. There is no law stating that diagrams must fill the line width; to the contrary, diagrams shorter than the line width should be preferred, in my opinion, if possible.

Comment: This is not really the problem mentioned above. If I don't specified any `ylabel`, the `tikzpicture` is both centered and fitting the linewidth. It is the same if I only have the left yaxis, even with an `ylabel`. This shows that the problem comes from the computation of the bounding box or something similar in the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @Sigmun Not at all. You're asking that the *axis* is as wide as the line width, not the whole diagram. That's how `pgf` interprets the instruction `width=\linewidth` and it's quite natural.

Comment: I am asking that both plots are as wide as the line width. There is two `axis` environment in my `tikzpicture` and I don't understand why it can interpret the width of the same plot without `ylabel` and not with them.

Comment: Try to remove them, and you will see that the `ytick` on the right axis aren't overlapping the margin as they do if left `ylabel` is specified.

Comment: @Sigmun See it in this way: if `pgf` interpreted `width=\linewidth` as you wish, the two diagrams would *not* be superimposed. It can exactly superimpose them *because* it doesn't take the label into account. I guess that `pgf` leaves also some room for the tick labels, but of course *not* for the `ylabel`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't take the label into account." ? Because this is what I am pointing out on this kind of plot (It does take `ylabel` into account if there is only one y axis used)